# Wrong configuration npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

I have reinstalled the npm and I am trying to run a command npm start however I get the message as below. Unfortunately, my ideas are over. Can anyone help me?
I installed version 2.3.4, but it did not work

```
@angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.4.0 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'   
ERROR in C:/Users/Desktop/office/node_modules/frontend-components/lib/multi-application/dynamic-form/fields/employment-field/employment-field.component.ts (121,5): Type '{ averageIncome: FormControl; pensionerCardId: FormControl; companyName: FormControl; companyNip:...' is not assignable to type 'Options<FormControl>'.
Property 'name' is missing in type '{ averageIncome: FormControl; pensionerCardId: FormControl; companyName: FormControl; companyNip:...'.
ERROR in C:/Users/Desktop/office/backoffice/node_modules/fobos-frontend-components/lib/multi-application/dynamic-form/fields/employment-field/employment-field.component.ts (141,5): Type '{ averageIncome: false; pensionerCardId: false; companyName: false; companyNip: false; phoneNumbe...' is not assignable to type 'Options<boolean>'.
Property 'name' is missing in type '{ averageIncome: false; pensionerCardId: false; companyName: false; companyNip: false; phoneNumbe...'.
ERROR in C:/Users/Desktop/office/backoffice/src/app/campaigns/campaign-file/campaign-file.resolver.ts (59,5): Type '{ periodType: "Days"; startPeriod: number; endPeriod: number; startNetAmount: number; application...' is not assignable to type 'CampaignFinancialParameters'.
Property 'startPeriodType' is missing in type '{ periodType: "Days"; startPeriod: number; endPeriod: number; startNetAmount: number; application...'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It says in the error message returned to run the command `npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'`

Once you run that it should install a compatible version of typescript.

Comment: what is the response? also is this installed just for a project or globally. if it's global first try `npm uninstall -g typescript` if it's not global than try just `npm uninstall typescript` then install typescript again with `npm install -g [package name/version]` if it's global or `npm install [package name/version]` if it's not.

Comment: This is the correct answer but it shouldn't be necessary to downgrade. I've ran and successfully shipped applications using much higher TypeScript versions against that version of Angular.

Comment: That's a good point @AluanHaddad. So some other dependency is forcing the typescript version restriction you think?